# Can ping, but cannot ssh or ssh-copy-id between two Pis connected over Ethernet

Tags: ssh, ethernet, cluster, ping

I am trying to cluster two Pis, one 3A+ and one 0, by connecting them over Ethernet. They are connected directly via an Ethernet cable with Ethernet-to-USB/MicroUSB adapters on either side of the connection.

1. I have added different static ip_addresses (that are both distinct from addresses used for wlan0) to both Pis by editing /etc/dhcpcd.conf on each.
2. I have enabled ssh on boot by adding the blank magic 'ssh' file to both of the Pis /boot folders.
3. I have also generated ssh keys on both devices.

I can ping each Pi from the other successfully (0% packet loss), but when I attempt to ssh (or ssh-copy-id) from one to the other, the results are undesirable. When I attempt to ssh to the Pi0 from the Pi3A+, the network is unreachable. When I attempt to ssh to the 3A+ from the 0, the connection times out.

Does anyone have any idea what I can try to fix this?

Comment: Can you check that you can ssh into each of the pis from itself?  if they cannot then run raspi-config and check that ssh is indeed enabled.  It sounds like pi0 does not have networking/routing set up correctly.  You will probably have to provide more information such as output from ifconfig and net stat commands before anyone can help.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the contents of `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` and the output of `ip addr` and `route` on both systems and the `ping` and `ssh` commands with the output or error messages.